# jquery - replace matched character

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to replace a comma followed by a < br > so I used regex et replace method to do that:

```
var str = "<a class=added> ,,, ,, blbl;test, </a><br>, <a class=added>"
str = str.replace(/br>(,\s)/g, " "); 
alert(str);
```

In the result I noticed that 'br>' was also removed and it is not the exected result.
Is there anything wrong with my regex?

```
"<a class=added> ,,, ,, blbl;test, </a>< <a class=added>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the regex match correctly however you are **not** replacing correctly. This should be your replace string:

`"br> "`

as follows:

```
>>> str = str.replace(/br>(,\s)/g, "br> ");
"<a class=added> ,,, ,, blbl;test, </a><br> <a class=added>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove all comma followed by a white space by use following Pattern,

Check this [Demo Pattern](http://www.regexr.com/38lr8)

#### Pattern

```
/(\s,+)/g
```

Check this [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nyEG/)

#### jQuery

```
var str = "<a class=added> ,,, ,, blbl;test, </a><br>, <a class=added>"
str = str.replace(/(\s,+)/g, " "); 
alert(str);
```

#### Result

```
<a class=added>   blbl;test, </a><br>, <a class=added>
```

Comment: I'm only want to replace commas followed by 'br>'. Thanks for your reponse

Comment: but you know what your question meaning. Why you take my more effort without you no need.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake in my question. very sorry.
I edited my question